# dynamic datatype not working in SSIS script task

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I declared a variable as below in script task

```
dynamic sqldata = Dts.Variables["User::sqldata"].Value;
```

When I try to click **OK** for script task component, error coming as below

[image]

But when I replace **dynamic** keyword with **object or var**, which works fine.

So why dynamic datatype not working in script task?

Comment: Which error do you get inside your script task? You most have some kinda error message.

Comment: no compilation errors inside script task project, all green and no reds

Comment: If i try to make my variable into a dynamic variable i dont get any errors

Comment: Have you tried to set your variable into ReadOnlyVariables? Cant see if you have it in ReadWriteVariables?

Comment: What version of ssis?

Comment: 2015 SSDT tools

Answer (score 2):

stumbled across query when I had this same error myself so I thought I'd share my findings. My solution was to add Microsoft.CSharp as a reference when editing the script.

1. Edit the script component in the dataflow
2. Edit the script
3. Right click on References in the Solution Explorer
4. Add the reference "Microsoft.CSharp"
5. Use it in your class - 
   Using Microsoft.CSharp;

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot find data type dbo.type  in ssis

Change it into:

```
case "Double": return "[nvarchar](250)";
```

Comment: Is that a quote of an error message you get and want help with? Is this an attempt to answer according to [answer]? In that case please [edit] and make that more obious. Currently this post does not give an impression of being an attempt to answer the question at the top of this page, but it should.

Comment: The edit by @Dominique seems quite plausible (thanks), but if you are fine with it, this post now now turned into a code only answer, for which the following hint is applicable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.