# SSIS - "There was an error while building."

Tags: ssis, script-component

does anyone had this issue before? When I try to build a Script Component in SSIS but get the following error:

[image]

This does not give any context and actually it never starts the building so I don't know what is this.

Comment: I think we are going to need to see the code to answer this one

Comment: I don't think the issue is in the code because I have scripts running without issues and it also gives me this error. It seems like a visual studio error.

Comment: I have also tried on a colleague machine and the build worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. In my case, I was using a **dynamic** variable. I was trying to convert the variable's value to Int32 on the line of code that triggered the error.

The fix was adding a reference to Microsoft.CSharp. Visual Studio thinks that the reference is not needed, but the script will not compile without it.

Thanks to [C Woodward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10253474/c-woodward) for the answer on [dynamic data type not working in SSIS script task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459699/dynamic-datatype-not-working-in-ssis-script-task).